# use of .bool_set_inverse:N doesn't seem to match its definition

Tags: expl3, l3keys

Here is an mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \en_direct: { beginning }

\keys_define:nn { test }
{
  direct .bool_set:N = \test_direct_bool,
  indirect .bool_set_inverse:N = \test_direct_bool,
  direct .initial:n = {true},
  direct .default:n = {true},
  direct .code:n = {
    \bool_if:nTF {\test_direct_bool}
    {\cs_set:Nn \en_direct: { DIRECT }}
    {\cs_set:Nn \en_direct: { INDIRECT }}
  }, 
  indirect .initial:n = {false},
  indirect .default:n = {true},
  indirect .code:n = {
    \bool_if:nTF {\test_direct_bool}
    {\cs_set:Nn \en_direct: { DIRECT }}
    {\cs_set:Nn \en_direct: { INDIRECT }}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\seekey}{ m }{
  \bool_if:nTF {\use:c{test_#1_bool}} {key~#1~is~true} {key~#1~is~false}
  \qquad [\en_direct:]\par\noindent\hrulefill\par
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\valuekey}{m}
{
  \keys_set:nn { test }{ #1 } The~key~\textbf{#1}~has~been~set~to~TRUE.\par
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\seekey{direct}

\valuekey{direct} \seekey{direct}

\valuekey{indirect} \seekey{direct}

\end{document}
```

I expected the last bit to give ``key direct is false'' and "INDIRECT" as the value of `\en_direct:`
but it is not the case.

What am I missing or misunderstanding in the following bit of the expl3 documentation :

> `key  .bool_set_inverse:N = boolean`
>
> Defines `key` to set `boolean` to the logical inverse of `value` (which must be either true
> or false).

Comment: `.code:n` overwrites `.bool_set:N` and `.bool_set_inverse:N`. In `texdoc interface3`, sec. XXI.1 _Creating Keys_, it says "Key properties which define “actions”, such as `.code:n`, `.tl_set:N`, etc., **override** one another."

Comment: I’ve just read so much but a bit too late  :-(   Thanks. By the way `\keys_log:nn` is really useful (once you’ve noticed it).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in comments.